# Duplicate selection doesn't allow to pick an item without searching

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, duplicate-suggestions

When you are a mod or a gold-badge and you want to edit the list of duplicates, the standard model shows suggested questions. One cannot pick any of them and has to search for a suitable question instead. Clicking on these items doesn't do anything.

Comment: I can't reproduce. When I want to edit, I start with [blank list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ngt0.png) and only after searching for something, or pasting URL of a question, the list is populated as expected, and I can click an item and it add it to the list of duplicates. Can you please clarify what you see? Screenshots?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I can reproduce it. It's easy to check (if you are a gold badge holder, at least): click "Edit" on the list of dupes -> click "Add" -> *without typing anything* click on any of the questions you see in the list. Nothing happens. Search, then select and it works. [short video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3USmY.gif). Also if you click the *title* of the question when the dialog first shows [*it navigates to the other question*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfSee.gif).

Comment: @VLAZ that's the thing, without typing anything there is just blank list. Nothing to select from. And think that's the expected behavior, at least when editing the list, the ordinary dupe closure dialog would load related questions, but when editing think it was correct choice to start from blank state and let the editor choose manually. So anyway, the bug appears to be non empty list and I can't reproduce.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I can't reproduce your empty list. Do you have any userscripts running? Is it maybe a Meta thing?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSO: [Trouble adding duplicates to a closed question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419658/15497888)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed, as of Feb 6<sup>th</sup>, 2023.

You can now select one of the suggested duplicates, which loads the question into the popup box, then the "Add Original" button is enabled to confirm.

Comment: How come this got fixed without ever having [tag:status-review] tag? Did SE stop using this mechanism? (And it still has no status tag, but that's less important. I thought there was organized process for bugs)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars it was status-reviewed [on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419658/15497888) ([rev. 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/419658/3))

Comment: Good spot. Yes, the bug I picked up internally was linked to [the MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419658/trouble-adding-duplicates-to-a-closed-question) and I navigated to here from there. I've added the [status-completed] tag here now.

Comment: @HenryEcker so in such case there should be mechanism to link or show cross site duplicates, for those who don't frequent all the meta sites and have no way to know a bug is already in review, rejected, or fixed, when it's done on different site. (Not blaming you, just the system allowing such thing.)